# Spring Boot Security configuration throws UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am currently developing a web app and I program Java in Spring Boot for the backend. I am trying to configure Spring Security so that only users with a JWT-Token can access any endpoints. I am not even sure if that is the problem but every time I start the app, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/myapp/backend/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "filter" is null
```

The compiler marks the following code as deprecated:

```
package com.myapp.backend.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import jakarta.servlet.Filter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/auth/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter,  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
                
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an `@ RequiredArgsConstructor` annotation, but no required fields. Make those fields `final` so they are required and the proper constructor is created. Or switch to the `@AllArgsConstructor` in stead. Or ditch lombok and just write the constructor yourself (which is my preferred way of doing things like this).

Answer (score 0):

[M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) answered the question. The problem was the Dependency Injection. Both attributes have to be either final in this scenario since I am using Lombok with the @RequiredArgsConstructor